# Singleton with parameter initialisation

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm wondering whats the best way to make a safe singleton that needs to be called with an `initialise()` with arguments, before it will return a valid object using the `getInstance()` call. E.g.

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

class MySingleton {
public:
    static void initialise(const std::string& myName) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(MySingleton::m_initMutex);
        if (!MySingleton::m_initialised) {
             m_self = std::shared_ptr<MySingleton>(new MySingleton(myName));
             MySingleton::m_initialised = true;
        }
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<MySingleton> getInstance(){
        if ( MySingleton::m_initialised.load()) {
            return m_self;
        } else {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    MySingleton(const MySingleton&) = delete;
    MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton&) = delete;
private:
    MySingleton(const std::string myName) : m_myName(myName) {}
    
    static std::shared_ptr<MySingleton> m_self;
    static std::mutex m_initMutex;
    static std::atomic<bool> m_initialised;

    std::string m_myName;
};

std::shared_ptr<MySingleton> MySingleton::m_self{nullptr};
std::atomic<bool> MySingleton::m_initialised{false};
std::mutex MySingleton::m_initMutex;
```

Is there anything dangerous/not thread safe about this? Is there a cleaner/better way to approach this?

Comment: Just a general answer: Singletons are global state and global state is considered an anti-pattern nowadays. And global state is very often a problem in combination with multithreading.

Comment: initialization that needs to happen before getting an instance is typically dont in the constructor.

Comment: just use the meyers singleton, its thread safe and simple.

Comment: You use a shared pointer to be able to ... never deallocate the object anyway. And an atomic bool to ... do not very much. It would be nice for the getter to notice that it is uninitialized and perform the init automatically. That way it would be usable in static initializations before main.

Comment: I'd like to initialise the static object with some parameters, before being able to call `getInstance`, and I specifically want them to be separate calls.

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me. Since you need separate initialization, Meyers Singleton cannot be used directly. Meyers Singleton can be used indirectly, but I do not think such a solution will be simpler or cleaner (I started writing an answer doing that, but it did not turn out well). Consider changing the shared pointer to just a pointer, though. It does not serve any purpose.

Comment: As `m_self` is `static`, the `shared_ptr` will never destroy the object once created. Should the singleton be destroyed, when no pointer to instances are around any more? Instead of the `atomic<bool>` you could just use `volatile` so that other threads see a change in the varible, is there a difference?; and also you could remove the bool and signify uninitialized with a `m_self` being a `nullptr`.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I'm of the opinion that singleton is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Sebastian DON'T use `volitile` for multithreading in C++ and don't advice it. C++ has its own mechanisms. The standards committee is now even considering deprecating and later removing it from the standard, because it's misused so often. [Read the cpp core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rconc-volatile)

Comment: `volatile` often is used in a wrong way. But I think here it would be suitable and would do what it should.

Comment: @Sebastian "signify uninitialized with a m_self being a nullptr" - is checking `operator bool` thread-safe? I read that the ref count of shared_ptr is indeed atomic, so it does feel that way, but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: The thread synchronization part is simplified in your case: The initializing one reads and writes once (and has a mutex) and the one getting the instance just reads. You are right, it probably does not work with `shared_ptr` as you are reading the same instance of the pointer compared to the same object pointed to. So you can use a `nullptr` only with a normal pointer in this case.

Comment: Normally aligned writes with the bitsize of the system are atomic. Is this guaranteed by the standard? Depending on implementation the `shared_ptr` could be larger than 8 bytes (for 64 bits). According to cppreference it typically is 16 bytes. Then writing to it may overlap reading. You could (but would not want to) put the initialization mutex around getting an instance. So best would be to just get rid of `shared_ptr`, if you do not use its functionality of destroying the singleton at the very moment, when no thread needs it any more.

Comment: If you want to use `shared_ptr` functionality, then you would have to use `weak_ptr` for storage in `MySingleton`. Otherwise there is always a full ptr left and the instance would not be destroyed.

Comment: One critical problem in this code with atomic bool as well as with volatile bool is that the assignment of `m_self` and `m_initialized` could be reordered inside the mutex. The bool can be set to true before the instance is set. As `getInstance()` has no mutex, it can run at the same time and read the unset ptr. This problem would not happen without bool and only a standard pointer with `nullptr` signifying uninitialized, as we would have only one variable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal Meyers-like singleton with initialisation.

```
class Singleton
{
  private:
    int data;
    Singleton(int d) : data(d) {};
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    void operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
  public:
    int getData() { return data; }

    static Singleton& instance(std::function<Singleton()> *init = nullptr) {
        static Singleton s{(*init)()};
        return s;
    }

    static void initialize(int d) {
        std::function<Singleton()> init = [d]() { return Singleton(d); };
        instance(&init);
    }
};
```

If you call `instance` without calling `initialize` first, it will crash on dereferencing a null pointer (of course feel free to insert asserts/checks to catch this in debug mode, or in release mode if you are so inclined).

This requires C++17; for earlier versions of the language, replace `delete` with `default`.

Comment: Perhaps one could make this more safe to use: If a constructor throws during static initialization, the static initialization is tried again next time the function is called. Perhaps an exception could be raised (inside the constructor) instead of dereferencing a nullptr (outside).

Comment: _"it will crash on dereferencing a null pointer"_ well, actually dereferencing a null pointer is UB, so that's not guaranteed to happen. It's implementation defined. It's not good practice to rely on UB.

Comment: You can use `init ? (*init)() : throw std::runtime_error("Singleton not initialized!")` instead of current `(*init)()`. This will ensure that Singleton doesn't crash on null pointer but throws nice exception instead. Throwing exception will also allow to do a second try of singleton initalization with passing non-null pointer. By standard if during initialization of `static` variable exception is thrown then second call to same function will try to initialize `static` variable once again.

Answer (score 2):

According to C++ standard any `static` variable inside function's body is always protected with atomic bool (to check if it is initialized) and intialization is protected with mutex.

This makes `static` variable a very handy tool to create simplest yet thread safe solution for implementing Singleton concept. I do this in following 5 lines of code, together with usage of [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to pass initial value. Optional's method `.value()` throws an exception if we forget to pass init value for the first time.

As you see I made Singleton function templated so you can store any type inside and also added second optional UniqueTag param, so that you can create several singleton's out of one type.

To remind, any templated function has its own static variable instance for every instantiation of a template. So all singletons have different static variable inside.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/xY489eEKr)

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename UnqiueTag = void>
T const & Singleton(std::optional<T> const & init = std::nullopt) {
    static T val{init.value()};
    return val;
}

int main() {
    struct First {};
    struct Second {};
    std::cout
        << Singleton<int, First>(123) << " "
        << Singleton<int, First>() << " "
        << Singleton<int, Second>(456) << " "
        << Singleton<int, Second>() << " "
        << Singleton<std::string>("Hello!") << " "
        << Singleton<std::string>() << " "
        << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
123 123 456 456 Hello! Hello!
```

Comment: The template parameter type cannot be deduced from the function parameter because of the function parameter type actually being `std::optional<T>`?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, because it is optional and not bare T, because of this it is not deduced. More than that I actually meant my implementation so that you always pass first template parameter explicitly, so that all uses of singleton can explicitly tell you what type it has. Because you just pass optional very first time, and then many times use `Singleton<MyType>()` without function arguments. Actually it is better to suggest for you to make type alias `using FirstSingleton = Singleton<int, MyTag>;` or `using SecondSingleton = Singleton<int>;`.